# How to configure axis2 in AWS server?

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, war, apache-axis

I want to deploy java application with axis2 in my aws ec2 instance and I tried to configure axis2 on tomcat
I successfully installed tomcat7 and it shows in my public DNS
 [tomcat7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDOrJ.jpg)
But after I dropped the axis2.war in /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps
I cannot get access to /axis from my public DNS [axis2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNn6O.jpg)

Is there any blog or other resource to provide any instructions? Or any other ways to deploy my web service

Comment: Did you restart Tomcat after dropping the war file in there?

Comment: yeah, I restarted but it does not work

Comment: Are there any errors in catalina.out?